# Spring component detection without xml bean definitions

Tags: spring, annotations, javabeans

Is it correct that one can create spring beans using just the `@Component` annotation as long as context component scanning is configured?

Using spring 3.0.5 with Java 6.

My test case is:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring-bean.xml"})

public class ServerServiceUnitTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private ServerService serverService;

    @Test
    public void test_server_service() throws Exception {
           serverService.doSomething();
           //additional test code here
        }
}
```

The `spring-bean.xml` file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

My class I want to be a bean is:

```
@Component("ServerService")
public class ServerServiceImpl implements ServerService {
    private static final String SERVER_NAME = "test.nowhere.com";
        //method definitions.....'
}
```

Should that not be sufficient for spring to instantiate the `ServerService` bean and do the autowiring?

The error I get is:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [serversystem.ServerService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not defined in your `spring-beans.xml` the `<context:component-scan>` element:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="the.package.with.your.service"/>
```

The inclusion of

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

only allows you to use `@Required`, `@Autowired`, and `@Inject` annotations for configuration.  By specifying the `<context:component-scan>`, you are telling Spring where to look for `@Component` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using annotated controllers and other features
you should include

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

you should use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="spring3.example.controllers"/>
```

to specify the package in which controller classes are stored.